# drawing graphs from a dataframe by group and between certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a financial dataset that contains measures for some markets during some time periods.

```
market  date    metric1    metric2    metric3
ASX     2000            
ASX     2001            
ASX     2002            
ASX     2003            
TSX     2000            
TSX     2001            
TSX     2002            
TSX     2003            
TSX     2004            
NYSE    2000            
NYSE    2001            
NYSE    2002            
NYSE    2003            
NYSE    2004
```

Metric1 to metric3 contains numerical values. I would like to draw some line or bar graphs that group by market and between some date values, say 2000 and 2002 in this example. my date variable could be yearmonth (e.g. 200101, 200102). Is there a way to tell python that it is yearmonth so there is no gap between 200112 and 200201?
I am using matplotlib and pandas.

Comment: There are multiple ways to plot out the elements. What is your desired plot? If we have dates on the X-axis, value of metric on Y-axis, do you want one plot with 9 lines (one per metric per market), 3 subplot per metric (each with one line per market), or 3 subplots per market with one line per metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to draw some line or bar graphs that group by market and
>   between some date values, say 2000 and 2002 in this example

I will be using in both cases this as my data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
df = pd.DataFrame({'market': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                       'date': [2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001], 
                       'm1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
                       'm2': [4, 3, 5, 2, 1, 0]})
```

Use [@Ami Tavory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823583/4225467) to format the date correctly

For one subplot per metric:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

df.pivot(columns='market', index='date', values='m1').plot(ax=ax[0])
df.pivot(columns='market', index='date', values='m2').plot(ax=ax[1])

plt.plot()
```

[image: One subplot per metric]

For one subplot per market:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

df[df.market=='A'].plot(x='date', y=['m1', 'm2'], ax=ax[0])
df[df.market=='B'].plot(x='date', y=['m1', 'm2'], ax=ax[1])
df[df.market=='C'].plot(x='date', y=['m1', 'm2'], ax=ax[2])

plt.plot()
```

[image: One subplot per market]

Comment: Thanks. So I created a 'year' column. How do I draw a graph that takes only observation between 2015 and 2017 without creating another dataframe? also, how do I add label in the graph using just pd.plot()?

Comment: You can add a graph title, by just adding `the pd.plot(..., title='My title')`. Check the documentation on the pandas plotting function for more options in there: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html 
Also, this page of the docs has a ton of examples that may come useful: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html

Comment: For the filtering of the dataframe, for the first approach add that filter condition before the pivot: `df[df['year'].between(2015,2017)].pivot(..).plot(..)`.. in the second approach there is already a filter so add it in there: `df[(df.market=='A') & (df.year.between(2015,2017)) ].plot(..)`

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to tell python that it is yearmonth so there is no gap between 200112 and 200201?

From your description it sounds like you might be looking for `pd.Series.between`. You could use it, e.g., as

```
 df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date) # "tell" pandas it is dates.

 df[df.date.between(pd.to_datetime('2011-01'), pd.to_datetime('2012'))]
```

As you can see, `pd.to_datetime` can take in different formats (with moth and date or without). Also note that `between` has an `inclusive` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. but my input is numeric e.g. 200101. how can I tell python that this is just yearmonth ?